# How do I compare Time values in a pandas dataframe column to a defined time values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have a dataframe which has time values in 24 hour format, example 06:55:07, 20:09:42 etc. I want to categorize these as day if value is between 6:30 am and 6:30 pm and night otherwise. What is the best way to do this?
This is what I've tried:

```
def datetimeToDayNight(column, daytime='06:30:00', nighttime='18:30:00'):
    """Convert datetime to string 'Day' or 'Night'."""
    stringday= datetime.strptime(daytime, '%H:%M:%S').time()
    stringnight = datetime.strptime(nighttime, '%H:%M:%S').time()
    if (column > stringday & column > stringnight):
        return 'Day'
    else:
        return 'Night'

df['Day_Night']= datetimeToDayNight(df['Time'])


    
   I get the following error when I try this:
   TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have this dataframe (the "Time" column is string):

```
       Time
0  02:55:07
1  04:55:07
2  06:55:07
3  08:55:07
4  20:55:07
5  21:55:07
```

Then you can use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html#pandas.Series.between) with `np.where`:

```py
df["Day_Night"] = np.where(
    pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"]).between("06:30:00", "18:30:00"), "Day", "Night"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       Time Day_Night
0  02:55:07     Night
1  04:55:07     Night
2  06:55:07       Day
3  08:55:07       Day
4  20:55:07     Night
5  21:55:07     Night
```